# Update winston logger

Tags: node.js, logging, backend, winston

There is an old way to use the winston logger. (version below 2.4.4)

```js
  var winston = require('winston');
 
  //
  // Configure CLI output on the default logger
  //
  winston.cli();
```

At the moment, winston version: 3.3.3.

```js
const winston = require('winston');

const myformat = winston.format.cli({ colors: { info: 'green' }});


const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
            format: myformat
        })
    ]
});

winston.add(logger)
```

With this way, the output is
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Who knows how to initialize winston to convert "% s:% s" to normal text?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  format: winston.format.splat(),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format
    })
  ]
});
```

need add format